Axios GET fail, [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting (express js, mysql, react)
I run my backend smoothly at first, but since the axios won't to retrieve GET data from backend, i change the port to 8000 in index.js file, and then the backend server continuously crashed.

This is my index.js as server code:
import express from "express";
import mysql2 from "mysql2";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();
const db = mysql2.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "luthfi",
  password: "luthfi@MYSQL",
  database: "mastercrm",
  port: "8000",
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json("This is representative the json response success");
});

app.get("/data/contacts", (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json(data);
  });
});

app.get("/data/leads", (req, res) => {
  const q = "SELECT * FROM leads";
  db.query(q, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json(data);
  });
});

app.post("/data/contacts", (req, res) => {
  const q =
    "INSERT INTO contacts (`person`, `person_address`, `institution`, `position`, `institution_address`, `email_address`, `email_address2`, `phone`, `phone2`, `socmed_link`, `status`, `descriptions`) VALUES (?)";
  const values = [
    req.body.person,
    req.body.person_address,
    req.body.institution,
    req.body.position,
    req.body.institution_address,
    req.body.email_address,
    req.body.email_address2,
    req.body.phone,
    req.body.phone2,
    req.body.socmed_link,
    req.body.status,
    req.body.descriptions,
  ];
  db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json("Insert Data Dari Backend Berhasil");
  });
});

app.post("/data/leads", (req, res) => {
  const q =
    "INSERT INTO leads (`invoice_date`, `lead_title`, `sales_name`, `person`, `institution`, `descriptions`, `trade_value`, `lead_stage`, `lead_status`, `notes`, `deal_date`) VALUES (?)";
  const values = [
    "2024-05-04",
    "Penjualan IFP",
    "Dany",
    "Harry Tanoe",
    "SoundEye Production",
    "1 unit IFP Maxhub V6 ViewPro",
    126900000,
    "Baru",
    "Unqualified",
    "Percobaan insert data dari backend",
    "2024-05-04",
  ];
  db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json("Insert Data Dari Backend Berhasil");
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Berhasil terkoneksi ke backend!");
});

Also axios can't GET data, it shows cannot GET / in the browser. I try to switching each other between backend and frontend port but didn't work.
This is my frontend code:
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAllContacts = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/data/contacts");
        console.log(res);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    fetchAllContacts();
  }, []);
  return <div>Dashboard</div>;
};

export default Dashboard;

The path /data/contacts itself success showing json, but when i GET with axios, the page instead display the "/" path in index.js

It's saying it cannot connect to the MySQL server on port 8000. Since MySQL typically binds on port 3306, it's not clear why you're trying anything else

sorry i also confuse why the code become inline while i paste it here, Alright i just thinking the port only for express, but actually you right, the port option is mysql own thankyou

Based on this another question, Actually the problem is with the port 3000. When i terminate the react server, it says port 3000 is already in use, so i change to 3001, and react can display it's frontend, and express can provide data. the axios GET also success. Thank you everyone's to help.
